# JQuery Toggle Content

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidedown, slideup

I am trying to make a simple slideUp slideDown content

I have the following code so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    a {
        color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .first {
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #C00;
    }
    .text {
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: #666;
    }
    .subhead {
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #F90;
    }
    </style>
    <script  language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('li > ul').each(function(i) {
            // Find this list's parent list item.
            var parent_li = $(this).parent('li');
            var siblings_li = $(this).parent('li').siblings();

            var sub_ul = $(this).remove();
            parent_li.wrapInner('<a/>').find('a').click(function() {
                // Make the anchor toggle the leaf display.
               if (sub_ul.is(':hidden')){
                //siblings_li.slideUp('200');
                sub_ul.slideDown('200');}
                else {
                    sub_ul.slideUp('200');}
            });
            parent_li.append(sub_ul);
        });

        // Hide all lists except the outermost.
        $('ul ul').hide();
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="first">College Programs
        </span>
        <ul>
            <li class="text">We have a variety of programs. more more more more more more more more more more more</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span class="first">Programs
        </span>
        <ul>
            <li class="text">Each of our Colleges have various ..... COE shown below.</li>
          <li><span class="subhead">Computer Science
            </span>
            <ul>
              <li>Computer engineers analyze, design, operate and manage complex digital hardware, computer networks and large-scale software systems.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span class="subhead">Electrical Engineering
          </span>
            <ul>
              <li>Electrical engineers influence various sectors of society by analyzing, designing and implementing a wide range of systems.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="first">More Info</li>
    </ul>
```

Everything works fine, however I would like it so that when I click on one title, the others collapse. I.e., only one content can be seen at a time. and by default they should all be minimized (hidden). My issue is how can I make it so that it minimizes all the other content if one of them is shown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you user [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) to solve your problem. It has lots of handy configuration parameters (e.g. `animate` to animate changing panels).

[The library](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) has been used by thousands of people for quite some time so you can be confident that it is well tested and should work with no issues.

**EDIT**

You can add `accordion` to top level elements as well as children elements. Taking your example:

If you add an `id="topaccordion"` to the root `<ul>` element (`<ul id="topaccordion">`) and `id="subaccordion"` to `<li id="subaccordion"><span class="subhead">Computer Science</span>` then your JavaScript function could look like this:

```
$('#subaccordion').accordion();
$('#topaccordion').accordion();​
```

I have tested that and it work fine. You would probably need to work on CSS a bit (e.g. to change mouse cursor when hover on "clickable" element etc.) but from functionality point of view `accordion` does the job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked into Accordion. I liked it however it doesn't seem to support (or I don't know how to) subheadings. If you try the script above, there is a subheading (Computer and Electrical Engineering) which have their own content that is supposed to appear and disappear too. Any idea if I can do that using Accordion? If so could you please direct me?

Answer (score 1):

Just hide all the items before showing the selected one.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    // Cache commonly used selectors
    var uls = $('ul ul');

    $('li > ul').each(function(i) {

        // Find this list's parent list item.
        var parent_li = $(this).parent('li');
        var siblings_li = $(this).parent('li').siblings();

        var sub_ul = $(this).remove();
        parent_li.wrapInner('<a/>').find('a').click(function() {

            // Hide all items first
            uls.slideUp('200');

            // Make the anchor toggle the leaf display.
            if (sub_ul.is(':hidden')) {
                //siblings_li.slideUp('200');
                sub_ul.slideDown('200');
            }
            else {
                sub_ul.slideUp('200');
            }
        });
        parent_li.append(sub_ul);
    });

    // Hide all lists except the outermost.
    uls.hide();
});​
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MmG7a/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested the demo from jsfiddle. It works great except now the subheading Computer Engineering and Electrical Engineering don't seem to expand. It hides the content instead. Can you please tell me how to fix that too?